# Evaluate: $\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{1+5^{x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, logarithms

Evaluate:
$$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{1+5^{x}} dx$$

After checking f(-x) for odd/even function and not getting suitable results.

Let $$1+5^x=t$$
$$dx=\frac{dt}{log(5)(t-1)}$$
$$x^2=\frac{(t-1)^2}{(log(5))^2}$$
Limits changed from $[-2,2]$ to $[\frac{26}{25},26]$
$$\int_{\frac{26}{25}}^{26} \frac{(t-1)^2}{[(log(5))^2(t)(log(5)(t-1)]} dt$$
$$\frac{1}{(log(5))^3}\int_{\frac{26}{25}}^{26} \frac{t-1}{t} dt$$
This gave me some abomination that wasn't the answer I required which is 8/3.

I now also know the intended solution as mentioned below:

Let
$$I=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{1+5^{x}} dx$$
Using Identity of f(a+b-x) from definite integrals:
$$I=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{(2-2-x)^2}{1+5^{(2-2-x)}} dx$$
$$I=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{1+5^{(-x)}} dx$$
$$I=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{(5^x)x^2}{1+5^{x}} dx$$
$$2I=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{1+5^{x}}+\frac{(5^x)x^2}{1+5^{x}} dx$$
$$2I=\int_{-2}^{2} x^2 dx$$
$$I=\frac{1}{6}.[2^3-(-2^3)]=\frac{8}{3}$$

So why didn't my first approach work?

Comment: $x^2=\frac{(t-1)^2}{(log(5))^2}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choice of substitution does not work because if
$$t = 1+5^x,$$
then
$$x = \log_5 (t-1) = \frac{\color{red}{\log}\, (t-1)}{\log 5}$$
hence
$$x^2 = \frac{\color{red}{\log^2 (t-1)}}{\log^2 5}.$$  Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=-2}^2 \frac{x^2}{1+5^x} \, dx 
&= \int_{t=26/25}^{26} \frac{1}{t} \cdot \frac{\log^2 (t-1)}{\log^2 5} \cdot \frac{1}{(t-1) \log 5} \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\log^3 5} \int_{t=26/25}^{26} \frac{\log^2 (t-1)}{t(t-1)} \, dt,
\end{align}$$
and the antiderivative of this integrand does not have an elementary closed form.  It can be expressed in terms of the polylogarithm $$\operatorname{Li}_n(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^n},$$ but this is much too tedious compared to the intended solution.

Answer (score 3):

Letting $x\mapsto -x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^2}{1+5^x} d x & =\int_{-2}^2 \frac{(-x)^2}{1+5^{-x}} d x \\
& =\int_{-2}^2 \frac{5^x x^2}{5^x+1} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Averaging them yields $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^2}{1+5^x} d x & =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-2}^2\left(\frac{x^2}{1+5^x}+\frac{5^x x^2}{5^x+1}\right) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-2}^2 \frac{\left(1+5^x\right) x^2}{5^x+1} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-2}^2 \\
& =\frac{8}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Good work! But I think there are some careless mistakes. First the change of variable is $x$ to $-x$. Besides the term $3^x$ should be $5^x$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typos.  Fixed.